# concatinate values from an variables in to xml file

Tags: xml, bash, shell, for-loop, each

I have a variable $NAMES with 3 values.  I want to read the NAMES var and then with a statement replace the values in Conf.xml with the
values provided for $NAMES where I want each vlaue to be put in new
line in the order like:

```
 <name>Name1</name>
 <name>Name2</name>
 <name>Name3</name>
 

 NAMES = [Name1, Name2, Name3]
```

Conf.xml (initial state)

```
 <name>$NAMES</name>
```

desired state after the if statement is done:
Conf.xml

```
 <name>Name1</name>
 <name>Name2</name>
 <name>Name3</name>
```

I want with to do a If cycle or something to Replace the $NAMES value with each value from the variable without limitation if they are 2,3,1 or 5.

I tried with for but I can't replace the value after the first line and it does not work.

Have in mind this is part of provisioning so I can't really use some tools for xml.

Comment: Can the names contain special characters like `<`, `&` or `$'\x0b'`?

Comment: Well the names are names of domains in fact so they would most probably be like: test.domain.something

Comment: We miss some information: Where do you use the variable $NAMES? In a bash script? Is it an array? What have you coded so far?

Comment: this is a bash script used for provisioning basically the values for the NAMES variable are provided by the user basically in a type of array: [ Name1, Name2, Name3, Name4].
as I mentioned this is a domain name previously we used to have only one domain option now I want to be able read the array and then put the values one by one. 

for i in ${NAMES[@]}; do
      
      $NAMES += $i
     
      then
     sed -i "s|NAMES|$NAMES|g" "/opt/Conf.xml"

Sed can do the first value but not second or third.